# MySQL Query Transactions Within Set Time

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database and a `transactions` table. I would like to retrieve the last 10 transactions within the past hour, sorted in ascending order.

The query I am running is;

```
SELECT TimeStamp, SerialNo 
FROM transactions 
WHERE TimeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
ORDER BY TimeStamp ASC 
LIMIT 10
```

This produces a list of transactions as follows;

```
20551094 2017-08-15 15:47:12
20551095 2017-08-15 15:47:15
20551096 2017-08-15 15:47:38
20551097 2017-08-15 15:47:51
20551098 2017-08-15 15:47:56
20551099 2017-08-15 15:48:23
20551100 2017-08-15 15:48:23
20551101 2017-08-15 15:48:26
20551102 2017-08-15 15:48:29
```

I know there are *many* transactions **after** 15:48:29 that I'm not seeing.

Whenever I remove `LIMIT 10` I am presented with thousands of transactions, however I only want the most recent 10. Like below;

```
20551421 2017-08-15 16:47:55
20551422 2017-08-15 16:48:05
20551423 2017-08-15 16:48:06
20551424 2017-08-15 16:48:10
20551425 2017-08-15 16:48:15
20551426 2017-08-15 16:48:20
20551427 2017-08-15 16:48:26
20551428 2017-08-15 16:48:28
20551429 2017-08-15 16:48:30
20551430 2017-08-15 16:48:51
```

The reason I need them in this order is because I am displaying real time data on my website.

How can I achieve this? Feels like I'm doing something silly here!

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Do you know what `LIMIT 10` means?  You _won't_ see any records after `15:48:29` because that would mean returning more than 10 records.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY timestamp DESC` to get the most recent transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to retrieve the last 10 transactions within the past
>   hour, sorted in ascending order.

You need `ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC` to get the last rows. If you want to show them in ascending order, you can use a subquery and reverse the order in the outer query:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, SerialNo
FROM (
    SELECT TimeStamp, SerialNo 
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE TimeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
    LIMIT 10
) sub
ORDER BY TimeStamp ASC
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Paul Spiegel

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 10 latest transactions your code should be:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, SerialNo 
FROM transactions 
WHERE TimeStamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I.e. your `ORDER BY` should be `DESC`, since you want timestamps from latest to earliest, and then take the 10 latest with `LIMIT 10`

Comment: What do you want that you're not getting with your query?